# How to add a Bookmark control to a Word document at runtime

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to add in a C# application a bookmark to a particular range to my Word document at runtime . I have found one solution 
`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Bookmark bookmark1;
bookmark1 = this.Controls.AddBookmark(this.Paragraphs[1].Range, "bookmark1");`

But an error shows that the Windows form has no definition for `AddBookmark`. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using a WinForms application, therefore by using the keyword `this` it will refer to the form class you are using which does not have a definition for `Controls.AddBookmark`.

I suggest you take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx

This will show you how to create a word addin from which you can then use this code to add a bookmark.

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Bookmark bookmark1; bookmark1 = this.Controls.AddBookmark(this.Paragraphs[1].Range, "bookmark1");
```

Comment: can't we replace "this" with the variable of type supporting Addbookmark? I want to add this code to my managedMFC application

Comment: Yes it is possible using System.InteropServices, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx

Comment: Also take a look here this may help: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;316126

Comment: Without an implementation example, this answer is not useful.  For example:  The recommendation is to use an AddIn, which our application is using.  If you're attempting to access say, this.Controls.AddBookmark(this.Paragraphs[1].Range, "bookmark1");
from another class, how is this acheived?